# Siamese Network Triplet Loss for unlabeled images

Tags: machine-learning, similarity

Hi I am rather new to machine learning so I'm not really sure whether it's possible or not. Right now I'm trying to train a siamese network to identify whether an image is the same or not(by one-shot learning).

I've found a lot of implementations of such network on GitHub but they somehow need labeled data. Is it possible to do something similar with unlabeled data?